# Query for oneToMany relationship

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for solve my issue.

I have something like this.

```
class A{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a")
    private List<B> bs;
}

class B {
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    private String name;

    @Lob
    private byte[] img;
}
```

I want get all records from database except img field from relationship B.
Maybe create query in JPA but how do this correct?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could define img as lazy:

```
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Lob
private byte[] img;
```

That way the image is only loaded when you access the getter.

Second option is to create a DTO (Data transfer object) using the constructor expression:

```
package dto;

public class BDto {
   private final String name;
   private final A a;

   public BDto(String name, A a) {
       this.name = name;
       this.a = a;
   }

   // getters for both fields
}
```

Then you can create a query like:

```
select new dto.BDto(b.name, b.a) from B b where b.a.received = true
```

Important notice: the dto must be used in the query fully qualified (e.g. dto.BDto)

Comment: Thanks, it's helpfully. DTO looks very good but I need add some conditions.
'where a.received = true' etc
How can I access to A entity now ?

Comment: I answered in post below. @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) doesn't work :(

Comment: see my comment bellow